# Printing a "W" pattern with alphabets 'abcdefghi' for Python

Tags: python

I would like to ask a question regarding printing a "W" pattern through alphabets, here is my code but I got an output like this

```
def stringing(sentence,start):    
    if start == 'T':
        j = 0

        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(9):
                if col-row == 0 or row+col == 0 or row+col == 4 or col+row == 8 or col-row == 4:
                    print(sentence[j], end='')
                    j += 1
                else:
                    print(end=" ") 
            print()  

stringing('abcdefghi', 'T')

a   b   c
 d e f g 
  h   i
```

Can someone assist me in this matter? I would like to output as this

```
a   e   i
 b d f h
  c   g
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: print("a   e   i\n
 b d f h\n
  c   g")

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python rail-fence", you’ll find examples and other solutions that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  In general, your problem comes from making no attempt to deal with the input string left-to-right.  Get rid of your "row" loop: go column-by-column, and figure out which row gets each letter.  Print only after you've placed all the letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to give it a try. Was a little tricky, but no too bad. This is what I came up with. Tested and works for me even works with larger or shorter strings.

```
def stringing(sentence,start):    
    if start == 'T':

        offset1 = '   '
        offset2 = ' '
        str1 = ''
        str2 = ' '
        str3 = '  '

        str_number = 1
        for letter in sentence:

            if str_number % 4 == 1:
                str1 += letter+offset1

            if str_number % 2 == 0:
                str2 += letter+offset2              

            if str_number % 4 == 3:
                str3 += letter+offset1

            str_number+=1

        print(str1)
        print(str2)
        print(str3)


stringing('abcdefghi', 'T')
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link for your answer: [Wave Strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-string-wave-pattern/)

Here is the code copied from the website. I made some minor changes to relate it to the code you posted but anyways I hope this helps!

```
# Function that takes string 
# and zigzag offset 
def stringing(s, n): 

    # if offset is 1 
    if (n == 1): 

        # simply print the 
        # string and return 
        print(s)              
        return

    # Get length of the string 
    l = len(s) 

    # Create a 2d character array 
    a = [[" " for x in range(l)] for y in range(l)]  

    # for counting the  
    # rows of the ZigZag 
    row = 0
    for i in range(l): 

        # put characters in the matrix 
        a[row][i] = s[i];  

        # You have reached the bottom 
        if row == n - 1: 
            down = False    
        elif row == 0: 
            down = True
        if down == True: 
            row = row + 1
        else: 
            row = row - 1

    # Print the Zig-Zag String 
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(l): 
            print(str(a[i][j]), end = " ") 
        print() 

# Driver Code 
s = "abcdefghi"
n = 3 #represents the number of rows you want the wave to be
stringing(s, n) 

# This code is contributed  
# by ChitraNayal
```

The output should end up like the following:

```
a       e       i 
  b   d   f   h   
    c       g
```